# Passport - Register User & Pass Through info

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, npm, passport.js

I'm using Node/Express/Passport to register new users to my site. Simple enough. I'm using Mongoose to save data.

Goal: I'm attempting to have a person (WHO IS NOT LOGGED IN) answer a few questions. (Answers stored in vars) Then once they've finished I want them to register a new account.

When they register I want to pass along their username and password to the database, along with the data from their answers. So the goal is for this to happen in one click. This is what I have tried with no luck so far. Thanks for any help!!

```
var Beliefs = mongoose.model("Beliefs", beliefsSchema);
//handle sign up logic
app.post("/quiz", function(req, res){
    var newUser = new User({username: req.body.username});
    User.register(newUser, req.body.password, function(err, user){
        if(err){
            req.flash("error", err.message);
            console.log(err)

        }
        passport.authenticate("local")(req, res, function(){
          req.flash("success", "Welcome to JobQuiz " + user.username);
          res.redirect("jobquiz"); 
        });
    });
});
    //Create Answers
    Beliefs.create(req.body.beliefs, function(err, newBeliefs){
    Beliefs.create(req.body.beliefs2, function(err, newBeliefs2){
        if(err){
            console.log(err)
        } else {
            newBeliefs.author.id = req.user._id;
            newBeliefs.author.username = req.user.username;
            newBeliefs.save();
            newBeliefs2.author.id = req.user._id;
            newBeliefs2.author.username = req.user.username;
            newBeliefs2.save();
            console.log("User is:" + req.user.username)
            console.log(req.body.beliefs)
            res.redirect("/elementsintro");

        }
    });


});
```

Edit:

Here's my question. How would I go about saving the info to the USER during this process. My problem is when 
I add the code below:

newBeliefs.author.id = req.user._id;
 newBeliefs.author.username = req.user.username;

...I get an error that there is no User yet. How would solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can create new LocalStrategy that will register user if it doesn't exists or username and password matches existing user.

```
var passport = require('passport');
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;

passport.use('local-login-register', new LocalStrategy(
  function(username, password, done) {
    User.findOne({ username: username }, function (err, user) {
      if (err) { 
        return done(err); 
      }
      if (!user) {
        var newUser = new User({username: username});
        User.register(newUser, password, function(err, user){
            if(err){
                return done(err);
            }
            return done(null, user);
        });
      } else if (!user.validPassword(password)) {
        return done(null, false, { message: 'Username already exists. Incorrect password.' });
      } else {
        return done(null, user);
      }
    });
  }
));
```

Then register new endpoint:

```
app.post('/quiz', function(req, res, next) {
    passport.authenticate('local-login-register', function(err, user, info) {
        var quiz = req.body.quiz;

        if (err) { return next(err); }
        if (!user) { 
          // user needs to reanswer quiz or save user answers in session
          // and redirect user to new page with registraion form
        }

        // save here your quiz answers
    })(req, res, next);
});
```

Comment: Hey thanks! I cant quite get this to work. Check out the edit on my question. If I remove the  "newBeliefs.author.id = req.user._id" etc from the code it all works. How would I go about saving the info TO the user at the same time as registering?

Comment: You'd need to put this Beliefs code in Passport success function.

Comment: The problem is if I do that it says it cannot read property of the unknown username.